Powershell - Launch a program as admin using stored admin creds
For some reason when we updated a user from On Prem AD to Intune AD, a program called Brokers Ally stopped being able to open a local database. The only way it would open the database is if I use my ADM creds to run Brokers Ally. My client has used this program since 1998 and really wants to continue using this program. I have tried for hours on the phone with Brokers Ally support to recall the old database to work with his current Intune based account, with no avail. The quickest way to make a work around I could think of is letting the user run a PowerShell script that will load my stored admin creds to launch the BrokersAlly.exe to access his years worth of data.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you - Zelman
This is the code I have so far:
# Define the path for the encrypted credentials file
$credFilePath = "C:\BA9\encryptedCreds.xml"

# Function to securely store credentials
function Store-Credentials {
    # Prompt for user credentials
    $credential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter your credentials for Brokers Ally"

    # Convert credentials to XML and encrypt
    $credential | Export-Clixml -Path $credFilePath

    Write-Host "Credentials have been stored securely."
}

# Function to retrieve and use the stored credentials
function Launch-Program {
    if (Test-Path $credFilePath) {
        # Import the encrypted credentials
        $credential = Import-Clixml -Path $credFilePath
        
        # Start the program with the stored credentials
        $process = Start-Process "c:\BA9\allywin.exe" -Verb RunAs -Credential $credential
        
        Write-Host "Program launched successfully."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Credential file not found. Please store your credentials first."
    }
}

# Main execution block
Store-Credentials
Launch-Program

The portion of code I am having an issue with is  $process = Start-Process "c:\BA9\allywin.exe" -Verb RunAs -Credential $credential
These are the errors I am getting when I am running the Launch-Program function or when I just run the one line of code that I have above.
PS C:\Users\BrokerAlly> Launch-Program
Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:8 char:20

...  $process = Start-Process "c:\BA9\allywin.exe" -Verb RunAs -Credentia ...

CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand



PS C:\Users\BrokerAlly> Start-Process "c:\BA9\allywin.exe" -Verb RunAs -Credential $credential -Verbose
Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1

Start-Process "c:\BA9\allywin.exe" -Verb RunAs -Credential $credentia ...

  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand




I have tried the Start-Process a few ways and I am sure I am somewhat close to the answer but maybe lacking the understanding to get all the way there.
$process = Start-Process "c:\BA9\allywin.exe" -Credential (Get-Credential) -NoNewWindow
$process = Start-Process "c:\BA9\allywin.exe" -Verb RunAs -Credential $credential
$process = Start-Process "c:\BA9\allywin.exe" -Credential $credential
$process.verb = Start-Process "c:\BA9\allywin.exe" RunAs -Credential $credential

You cannot combine -Verb RunAs with -Credential - allowing that would amount to bypassing UAC. By default, you cannot avoid UAC dialogs. The only workarounds are insecure and therefore strongly discouraged - see the linked duplicate for details.
